# How do i update powerpoint with my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, powerpoint

Would really love to get some help here

I have the below data

| Country | Industry | Data X | Data Y | Data Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Singapore | Car | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| Singapore | Bike | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| Malaysia | Pastries | 5 | 7 | 10 |

I wish to update my slides with 'This slide contains data for [Country] in [Industry]
and another part of the slide includes a chart to include the values for Data X,Y and Z

instead of looping as follows:
for country, industry, X, Y, Z in df[["country_name", "industry_group_name","X" , "Y", "Z"]].values.tolist():

is there a way to capture all the individual row data in a list to update without having to mention each column names for eg X, Y, Z......

hope this isnt too confusing!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a nested loop (which loops through every possible combination of Country, Industry including pairs that don't exist), just loop through the rows and print the values in each row:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  print(row['Country'], row['Industry'])
  # if you want to update a value, just set it for the row:
  row['Country'] = 'new country' # this updates the row in the df
```